# how do I copy the Timestamp data type from Firestore to Cloud SQL Postgres?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm trying to duplicate a data from Firestore to Cloud SQL Postgres.

The data in Firestore looks like this

```
+users (Collection)
  +-uid (DocumentID)
     +-name (String)
     +-time (Timestamp)
```

So the code looks like this:

```
exports.replicateToPostgres = functions
  .firestore.document("users/{userId}")
  .onCreate((snap, context) => {
    if (!snap.exists) return null;
    // Create data to be written
    const uid = snap.id;
    const name = snap.get('name');

    // This is THE Firestore Timestamp data type ****
    const time = snap.get('time'); 

    // Connect to pool
    if (pgPool == null) {
      pgPool = new pg.Pool(pgConfig);
    }
   
    // Create in Postgres
    return pgPool.query(`insert into users values('${uid}', '${name}', ${time})`);
    
});
```

So the variable `time` is what holds the Timestamp from Firestore. And when I print it out it shows `[object Object]` in the Cloud Function log: (see the blue highlighted text)

[image]

Then when inserting it gives this error:

```
error: syntax error at or near "["
```

Which is expected because `[object Object]` is not a valid Postgres syntax.

So how do I actually copy the Timestamp data type from Firestore to Cloud SQL Postgres?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the property or method of the [`Timestamp`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.Timestamp) object that corresponds to your need.

For example:

- `valueOf()`, which converts this object to a primitive string
- `toMillis()`, which convert a timestamp to a numeric timestamp (in milliseconds since epoch)
- `seconds`
- etc..

---

For example:

```
// ...
const time = snap.get('time').seconds; 

// ...

// Create in Postgres
return pgPool.query(`insert into users values('${uid}', '${name}', ${time})`);
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the answer by @Renaud Tarnec

This is basically the same, but let me share it here anyway specially when you want to write it as `Timestamp` object in Postgres and to use `.toMillis()`

This is how I retrieve the Timestamp from `time` field in Firestore document:

```
const time = snap.get('time').toMillis();
```

And this is how I write it in Postgres:

```
return pgPool.query(`insert into users values('${uid}', '${name}', to_timestamp(${time}::double precision / 1000))`);
```

Notice that I use `to_timestamp(${time}::double precision / 1000))` to write it in Timestamp object in Postgres.